# How to connect extensions of remote VOIP over remote STUN server?

Tags: nat, docker, asterisk, voip

[Image of Architecture I am trying to setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufb8J.png)

I have configured the Asterisk server in a docker image and it's running,
I have also configured the STUN/TURN server and it's also running on the same virtual system.

Now, I try to connect my extensions but they drop after 10-15 mins if connection and don't connect after that.

The TURN server is a CoTURN server :   https://github.com/DreamNetwork/docker-coturn/blob/master/Dockerfile

The VOIP server is an Asterisk 12 server with FreePBX as the frontend. I am doing my configurations on the freePBX.

Initially, I was not able to connect which led me to setup the STUN server and even after that, I am not able to progress... 
Can anyone tell me what I can do to over the NAT, because if I setup a mobile-hotspot all connections work fine without STUN.

Comment: Why do you need STUN if your system works without it?

Comment: My system works only ion mobile internet. It does not work when I am trying to connect using my office router.

Comment: Try installing asterisk outside of Docker.

Comment: I setup the coturn server on a different virtual system and the phone extensions work perfectly. They have not deregistered for the past 2 days and all calls are working with decent quality.

Comment: So was the issue that the STUN was running on the same VM and so not doing any NAT transversal? What was the difference between the two setups that made the phones register?

Comment: When I tried to setup the STUN server on the same machine where the Asterisk server was setup,  ( I am not completely sure) they were using the same ports.
Asterisk server needs ports 5060 for SIP and 10000-2000 ports to route the RTP info. But it also needs to listen on port 3748 to get info from STUN/TURN. 
When the TURN/STUN server was on a different machine, it could work properly. 

Now, I have a really stable system where the extensions have been stable for a month and we are using it in the office. 
I will try to setup both on the same device and log the info to check what happens later